# ValidationError when instantiating SimpleNodeParser class from llama index

Tags: python, parsing, large-language-model, llama-index

Taking straight from the docs ...

```
from llama_index.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader

# load the blogs in using the reader
docs = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()

# chunk up the blog posts into nodes
parser = SimpleNodeParser()
nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(docs)
```

Gives me this error:

```
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 8
      5 docs = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()
      7 # chunk up the blog posts into nodes
----> 8 parser = SimpleNodeParser()
      9 nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(docs)

File ~/Emily/trials/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py:341, in BaseModel.__init__(__pydantic_self__, **data)
    339 values, fields_set, validation_error = validate_model(__pydantic_self__.__class__, data)
    340 if validation_error:
--> 341     raise validation_error
    342 try:
    343     object_setattr(__pydantic_self__, '__dict__', values)

ValidationError: 1 validation error for SimpleNodeParser
text_splitter
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I am on an M1 Mac and in a virtual environment. How can I hunt down this error?

Comment: what is the content of your data directory, could you just check with sample.txt file first

Comment: The error is coming when I try to instantiate the SimpleNodeParser class. If I eliminate everything but this line I still get the error. Has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The Validation error is coming from not having a field `text_splitter` so I can get it to run by supplying one ... but this seems like a bug.

Comment: pip show llama-index. I able to run same program with Version: 0.7.21

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem (after updating from 0.7.x to 0.8.21).

To fix change

```
parser = SimpleNodeParser()
```

to

```
parser = SimpleNodeParser.from_defaults()
```

Comment: amazing, thank you